# Can I simplify the following template?

Tags: c++, templates

Edit:

Thanks for the excellent answers.  I clearly didn't give enough detail on my problem.  I have attempted to correct this:

I am updating some legacy code, and have several overloaded functions that have the following pattern:

```
void foo (Int bla, const char* bla1, const char* bla2, ...);
void foo (Int bla, SomeCustomContainer);
```

Now, we are phasing out the custom containers, and using std containers instead.  The signatures of the custom containers are such that I can template on the continainer, re-use the code, and simultaneously support legacy and new code until the legacy code is phased out.

My first try was:

```
template <typename ContainerT> void foo(int bla, ContainerT);
```

but the compiler spits out an error becuase it matches the templated function over the const char* signature.

Based on an answer on StackOverflow, I tried the following template signature:

```
template <typename ValT, template <typename, typename = std::allocator<ValT> >
          class ContainerT>
void foo(Int bla, const ContainerT<ValT>& rasInParams)
```

This solves my problem -- the compiler finds the right overload and everything works fine for my purposes.  My only complaint is this is a lot to parse for a colleague who is less comfortable with templates, and I'm wondering if there's a way to simplify this -- I'm thinking in terms of a type alias, but maybe someone knows a better way to solve my underlying overload resolution issue?

Comment: what do you expect by "easier to read"?

Comment: I think both answers are still valid for the updated question. All you have to do is to add `value_type` typedefs to `SomeCustomContainer` classes if they aren't there (or maybe you don't have to do even this using the trick with `begin()` in @sehe's answer)

Comment: @Anton Savin:  Sorry, I don't get what you're trying to say -- If it's a choice between my current solution and going through the various custom containers and modifying them (when the goal is just to delete them anyway), I prefer the current solution.  My issue is not that I need to know the value type, but that the compiler is finding the wrong function overload (not the templated implementation, but the accepting the char*'s).

Comment: @davidhigh -- I was hoping to write something along the lines of  "using ContainerT = /*some magic here*/", and then just use ContainerT in the variious declarations, so that I'm not duplicating template signatures all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

The sample doesn't work generically (imagine a container that doesn't take an allocator, or takes more than two type arguments, or, god forbid, non-type arguments).

My usual approach is just to

```
template <typename Container>
void foo(const ContainerT& rasInParams)
```

If you need to know the valuetype you can do anything like

```
typename Container::value_type
```

or

```
std::remove_reference<decltype(*rasInParams.begin())>::type
```

---

If you really need to embed a configurable container from a template template argument, you can use a a variadic signature for the nested one:

```
template<typename ValT, template<T...> class Container>
void foo() {
    Container<ValT, std::allocator<ValT> > x;
}
```

Another option is to go with a container "selector" meta-function. This is e.g. used in Boost Graph library:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#sec:choosing-graph-type

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write (provided you are using standard containers as parameters):

```
template <typename ContainerT>
void foo(const ContainerT& rasInParams) {
    using ValT = typename ContainerT::value_type;
    // ...
}
```

If you want `foo` not to participate in overload resolution if the argument is not a container, you can use SFINAE. This still looks simpler than your original code:

```
template <typename ContainerT, typename = ContainerT::value_type>
void foo(const ContainerT& rasInParams)
```

Comment: I think your last edit is going in the direction I want, but as written it doesn't resolve on my custom container.   I'm unclear what the typename = ContainerT::value_type does.